# Javascript: Bold String Before Specific Char

Tags: javascript

I have Javascript code that turns a whole string bold, however, I'd like to adapt the code to specifically bold only the part of the string that comes before the ':'

The code I currently have is:

```
function changeBrandName() 
{
  var prodList = document.querySelectorAll("h1.ProductList-title");
  for (i = 0, len = prodList.length; i < len; i++) 
  {
    var store = prodList[i].indexOf(":");

    for (j = 0; j < store; j++)
    {
      prodList[i].charAt[j].style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    } 
  }
}
```

Applying the fontWeight in this way isn't currently working - advice would be appreciated.

The full string is "Vifa: Pebble Grey Oslo Loudspeaker" - I'd like 'Vifa' to be in bold.

Comment: Than you are going to have to add span and format it...

Comment: You cannot add styles to characters, only to elements (tags).

Comment: Javascript can handle this by adding tags, etc. However, if you are allowed to create/edit the HTML, then use plain HTML/CSS to achieve this.

Comment: You have to fetch the innerHTML, slice it, wrap it with <b> tags then set it back. Also you don't need loops, you can use a forEach to iterate over your queried elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there must be a simpler solution by `split`, etc. but here's one way to do it for clarity

```
<h1 class="ProductList-title" style="font-weight: 100;">Vifa: Pebble Grey Oslo Loudspeaker</h1>

<script>
    function changeBrandName() {
        var prodList = document.querySelectorAll("h1.ProductList-title");
        for (var i = 0; i < prodList.length; i++) {
            var text = prodList[i].innerText;
            var index = text.indexOf(':');
            var lower = text.substring(0, index);
            var higher = text.substring(index + 1);
            prodList[i].innerHTML = '<b>' + lower + '</b>:' + higher;
        }
    }
    changeBrandName();
</script>
```

Comment: I think @connexo answer is better, no offense, it is much more succinct and uses modern features of javascript

Comment: @jo_va i know that, had to edit his original code for clarity as i mentioned and i do know that there are gonna be concise solutions.

Comment: @jo_va appreciate that and I don't disagree - unfortunately I'm working with squarespace and the changes I'm making are very restricted to their existing template structure etc. so I don't want to go beyond simplistic and risk breaking something else.

Answer (score 1):

Using good plain old vanilla Javascript:

```js
let h1s = document.querySelectorAll('.ProductList-title');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  for (const h1 of h1s) { 
    let [brand, text] = h1.textContent.split(':');
    h1.innerHTML = `<b>${brand}</b>: ${text}`
  }
  this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
})
```

```css
h1 { font-weight: normal; }
```

```html
<h1 class="ProductList-title">Porsche: Cayenne</h1>
<h1 class="ProductList-title">BMW: i8</h1>
<button id="btn" type="button">Click to self-destruct</button>
```

Comment: I like this answer!

Answer (score 0):

Using plain JavaScript, you have to iterate over your queried elements, fetch their `innerHTML`, tranform the html and then set it back.

To transform the HTML, I use `indexOf` to find the colon, then `slice` to split the string in two parts. I then reconstruct the string using a template string and `<b>` tags:

```js
const prodList = document.querySelectorAll('.ProductList-title');

Array.from(prodList).forEach(elem => {
  const text = elem.innerHTML;
  const idx = text.indexOf(':');
  if (idx >= 0) {
    elem.innerHTML = `<b>${text.slice(0, idx)}</b>${text.slice(idx)}`;
  }
});
```

```css
h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="ProductList-title">Prod 1: blabla</h1>
<h1 class="ProductList-title">Prod 2: blabla</h1>
<h1 class="ProductList-title">Prod 3: blabla</h1>
<h1 class="ProductList-title">Prod 4 no colon blabla</h1>
```